# No Sound on Firefox or Chrome, Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, kubuntu, firefox, google-chrome

Amarok works fine, system sounds, local videos... but I get no sound in Firefox or Chrome on Youtube.  I even tried installing flash plugin for Firefox instead of HTML5, STILL no sound.

I really have no idea what to do next.  Googling hasn't come up with anything recent in this regard... (all versions from at least 2 years ago).

Has this happened to anyone else and do you know the solution?  Or specifically something I can look at in my configuration that might clue me in?

Thank you.

--

Firefox v47.0

Chrome v51.0.2704.106

Netflix, twitch and all others will not run in browser either.  It seems like only browser-related apps will not have sound.

I installed the restricted extras (codecs).

--

I have also tried installing freshplayerplugin, to no avail.

--

Another update...  I installed minitube and that works with youtube videos.  On the DOWNSIDE, I installed wine/playonlinux and installed a game (starstable online) and there is no sound in game.

This is frustrating.  I am sure there is some common denominator but I don't know what it is.

---

Driver information (thanks for the link):
http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=f49aa014a5845d49a61aa5225fbf42f1c3c44408

Comment: I should note this is a FRESH install.  From scratch.  Also updated to latest available version of plasma.  My headset is a logitech USB.  But sound from browser does not play on any output.

Comment: You can update/edit your question instead of adding comments. Have you tried [other sites that host videos](http://www.thetoptens.com/best-alternatives-youtube/) ? Do you have sound in them? It may be related to some codec missing.
Can you also check and post what versions of firefox and chrome you have? on the command line type `firefox --version` and `google-chrome --version` and post results.

Comment: Thanks, I added the version.  And yes, no site with video/sound plays the sound.  Video is fine.

Comment: You have the latest versions. Btw I just realised I hadn't installed restricted extras but youtube (video/sound) was working fine all this time. The common denominator is probably somewhere within the area of video/sound drivers. For that you 'll need post/research your specific hardware models and check for incompatibility problems.
Also with a little googling around I don't know if these can help your case: [1](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1769390), [2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10870131), [3](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1455816)

Answer (score 15):

Thanks to Karsus I was able to track down the information I needed!!! When you install `pavucontrol`:

```
apt install pavucontrol
```

then you can pinpoint applications and see/control what sound output devices they think they should be using.

I had to manually set my browsers to use my headset for output.  Sweet!  Thank you Karsus.